# MYSQL - sum values of rows from one table based on criteria from another

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to find out the correct SQL query to carry out the following:

I have 2 tables and want to count total sum values of rows from one of them based on criteria selected from the other.

```
table1
| id  | colour      | item
| ------------------| ----------|
| 1   | blue        | anorak
| 2   | blue        | jeans
| 3   | green       | t-shirt
| 4   | yellow      | t-shirt


table2
| id  | cost     |
| ---------------|
| 1   | 58       |
| 2   | 22       |
| 3   | 36       |
| 4   | 19       |
```

So for example how do I find out total cost of all blue items? (Should amount to 80)

If it were all in one table I could do:
SELECT SUM(cost) FROM table1 WHERE colour='blue';

How would I do this with the 2 tables?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is the same, you need to [join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) the tables

> ```
> SELECT SUM(cost) FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id WHERE colour='blue';
> ```
>
> ```
> | SUM(cost) |
> | --------: |
> |        80 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8dca14747e50a30c05193ea75d7d6655)*

Answer (score 0):

Perform a JOIN on the id column to connect the two tables. Then SUM items based on color.

```
-- Find the total cost where item colour is blue.
SELECT SUM(t2.cost) AS TotalCost
FROM Table2 t2
JOIN Table1 t1 ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE t1.colour = 'blue';
```

*Note: I used table aliases t1 and t2 for clarity. They are not strictly needed when column names do not overlap/conflict.*

If item count is needed, include the MySQL function COUNT() to find the number of matching rows in the set.

```
-- Find the number of items & total cost where item colour is blue.
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS BlueItemCount,
  SUM(t2.cost) AS CostOfBlueItems
FROM Table2 t2
JOIN Table1 t1 ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE t1.colour = 'blue';
```

Comment: This also seems to work well - thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can use where clause and IN operator to find sum of cost of specific product on table which has id exist on the table 2 and colour is blue.
simply, blue colors product ids should be find in query 1 with :

```
SELECT table1.id from table1 where table1.colour = "blue";
```

sum of cost find with :

```
 select sum(cost) from table2;
```

Join with in keyword :

```
select sum(cost) from table2 where table2.id in (SELECT table1.id from table1 where table1.colour = "blue")
```

in operator works like a loop and match founded id in where clause query.

Comment: will look into this as an alternative in the future - thanks for your time